# trying to get the movie details in omdbapi using async function and load it in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, json, object

I'm trying to use the omdbapi and I used async function to fetch the data. I convert the `const data` to an array using the `Object.key()` so that I can use the `map()` to send the data to innerHTML but it always says `undefined`. I wanted to convert the `data` into a new array using a `map()` and show it in the html using `movieHTML()`. Please help

```js
  

   const movieListEl = document.querySelector('.shows');
     async function main (event) {
     const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=39a36280&s=${encodeURI(event)}`;
     const search = await fetch(`${url}`);
     const data = await search.json();
     // console.log(data.Search)
     // if (data.Response === 'True') {
     //     console.log(data.Search)
     // }
     let dataKeys = Object.keys(data.Search);
   
     movieListEl.innerHTML = dataKeys.map((movie) => 
     console.log(movieHTML(movie))).join("");
     } 

     main('squid game');

    function movieHTML (details) {
    return `<div class="shows__content">
    <figure class="shows__poster">
        <img src="${details.Poster}" alt="" class="poster">
    </figure>
       <div class="poster__description">
        <h4 class="poster__title">${details.Title}</h4>
        <p class="poster__year">${details.Year}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
     `
     }
```

```html
 

<div class="shows">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `Object.keys`?:

```
let dataKeys = Object.keys(data.Search);

movieListEl.innerHTML = dataKeys.map((movie) => 
   console.log(movieHTML(movie))).join("");
}
```

If you examine your data, you'll see that `data.Search` is an array.  So its "keys" are the index values (0, 1, 2, etc.).  Sending those integer values to `movieHTML()` doesn't seem productive.

Instead of looping over the *indexes* of the array, loop over the array itself and send each object therein to the function:

```
movieListEl.innerHTML = data.Search.map((movie) => 
   console.log(movieHTML(movie))).join("");
}
```